# Pagination with Backbone.js and Marionette.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I’m using Backbone.js and I’d like to extend it with Marionette.js. One thing, that works in Backbone, but I couldn’t make it with Marionette views, is the way I handle pagination.
In Backbone I have a method called pagination just inside the Backbone.Collection that looks like this:

```
var ordersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: 'collection',
        model: Order,
        pagination: function(page) {
            perPage = 10;
            var collection = this;
            collection = _(collection.rest(perPage * page));
            collection = _(collection.first(perPage));
            return collection;
        }
    });
```

Then I can create paginated collection just like this:

```
ordersCollection = new OrdersCollection();
ordersCollection.fetch();
ordersFirstPage = ordersCollection.pagination(1);
```

But when I try to pass this collection to Marionette.CompositeView, I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

I know that it’s because of my pagination function doesn’t return collection in the exact Backbone.Collection format. So I tried to fix it using:

```
ordersFirstPage = new Backbone.Collection(ordersFirstPage)
```

The TypeError disappeared, but then the values passed by CompositeView to its template behaved as empty.

Any ideas, how to modify either the collection object or the pagination function to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've managed it by using _.flatten() in pagination function. So I used flatten on the result of _.first() method used in collection.

My pagination collection now look like this:

```
var ordersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: 'collection',
        model: Order,
        pagination: function(page) {
            perPage = 10;
            var collection = this;
            collection = _(collection.rest(perPage * page));
            collection = _(collection.first(perPage));
            collection = _(collection).flatten(true);
            return collection;
        }
    });
```

And it seems to be the most simple and elegant solution for pagination of Backbone/Marionette collections.

Comment: your offset is not correct, for example `page = 5`, `collection.length = 49`, `perPage * page` (10 * 5) and it's 50, `collection.rest(50)` that does not give any results,  but with `offset = page <= 1 ? 0 : (page - 1) * perPage` everything gets split correctly and on your 5th page will be 9 records.

Answer (score 0):

You should not build a Backbone.Collection but a 'ordersCollection'. E.g:

```
ordersFistPage = new OrdersCollection(ordersCollection.pagination(1));
```

And you should check if the values you want to access is in the CompositeView(the collection should have the data, you can set the proprieties of the collection) or the ItemView of the CompositeView (the models from your collection should have the data).

Comment: Still I can't approach collection's models in template.

Comment: Instead of valid array of models, it adds models array under _wrapped value in the attributes value inside collection object.

Comment: why do you need the _() ?

Comment: I use _() to call underscore.js.

Comment: but you will return a underscore wrapped model array. try        collection = collection.first(perPage);

Comment: collection.first(perPage) won't work, because since there is _(collection.rest(perPage * page)), collection is no longer backbonone.collection, but it becomes an array which doesn't have method first